# Widget.Variable Does not work to access string variable form stful constructor

Tags: flutter, android-studio, widget

I build a constructor in stateful class that take one string parameter, then when I call this parameter using widget.label, it gives me this error

"Invalid constant value."

here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldDecoration extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? label;
  const TextFieldDecoration({Key? key, this.label}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _TextFieldDecorationState createState() => _TextFieldDecorationState();
}

class _TextFieldDecorationState extends State<TextFieldDecoration> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
        labelText: widget.label,
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
        color:  Color(0xff1f8ac0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try 
labelText: widget.label.toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you defined your `TextField` as constant but you variable cannot be constant. To fix your issue, just remove `const` in front of `TextField`.

```
class _TextFieldDecorationState extends State<TextFieldDecoration> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
        labelText: widget.label,
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
        color:  Color(0xff1f8ac0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```